# When was the famous "sudo warning" introduced? Under what background? By whom?

Tags: history, unix

On all Unix-like operating systems, `sudo` is often provided as the standard package for executing commands as superuser (or an alternative user). When `sudo` is invoked by the user for the first time, many systems print the following well-known "Sudo Warning":

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
>
> #2) Think before you type.
>
> #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
>
> Password:

When was this warning message introduced to `sudo`? Under what background? By whom?

Comment: Oh, I never saw this message. =-O Does a "standard" Linux distribution count as "Unix-like" system?

Comment: @thebusybee I'm pretty sure the same implementation is also used on BSDs nowadays, its maintainer Todd C. Miller is heavily involved in the development of OpenBSD as well. Although OpenBSD doesn't ship `sudo` by default anymore.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/838/

Comment: @ChrisStratton It's funny that Gentoo has a USE flag "offensive" for "app-admin/sudo" package and it's switched off by default. The "this incident will be reported" line only shows up if the "offensive" flag is activated. Clearly many people thought the message was annoying...

Comment: @ChrisStratton while that comic is funny, it's... *wrong*.  (Which, of course, leads to https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @thebusybee I've seen it in Linux distributions. It only appears the first time you call sudo.

Comment: Time after time when I'm getting curious about new releases of some distributions I install some in virtual machines. Sometimes I run `sudo` but I never saw the warning. I'll try to remember the next times. Thanks, though!

Comment: @thebusybee Just to let you know, I just checked in a new installation of Archlinux and I got that message.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The message appears in `sudo`’s revision control (in its current guise) [in June 1993](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/c101e9572d7f), in the University of Colorado version of `sudo`, in a slightly shorter form:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local Systems
Administrator. It usually boils down to these two things:

        #1) Respect the privacy of others.
        #2) Think before you type.
```

This initial commit also introduced `sudo`’s [other famous message](https://xkcd.com/838/), “This incident will be reported.”

The author of the commit is Todd C. Miller, the maintainer of CU `sudo` (now plain `sudo`, still maintained by Todd), but the source code predates the commit; and while the source mentions Jeff Nieusma, the messages [predate his involvement too](https://www.quora.com/Who-wrote-the-message-that-comes-up-when-you-use-sudo-for-the-first-time/answer/Brian-Bi) and their author is presumably either Bob Coggeshall or Evi Nemeth (see also “[A Brief History of Sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/history.html)”). The source history doesn’t suggest any particular background to the change. The message is typical of warning messages which were displayed when logging in to academic systems at the time.

`sudo` was published in the *UNIX System Administration Handbook*, written by  Evi Nemeth, Garth Snyder, and Scott Seebass; [the version published in the first edition](https://archive.org/details/isbn_0139334416/page/468) doesn’t include a warning in the program itself, but the authors mention that users who were granted `sudo` access were sent a (lengthy) email reminding them of the responsibilities associated with that privilege.

The third item was [added in January 2004](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/ebd5a76ccd7e), with a more interesting commit message:

> Add Stan Lee / Uncle Ben quote to the lecture from RedHat

Said quote (which, as [Tommy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4147/tommy) [points out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12521/when-was-the-famous-sudo-warning-introduced-under-what-background-by-whom#comment39312_12522), [wasn’t coined by Stan Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_great_power_comes_great_responsibility)) was added to Red Hat’s `sudo` package as a patch on top of version 1.6.6, in June 2002.

---

Historical artifacts: [these `net.sources` archives](https://archive.org/download/usenet-net/net.sources.mbox.zip) contain two versions of `sudo`, posted by Cliff Spencer and Don Gworek in December 1985 (also available in the UTZOO tapes); [this `unix-pc.sources` archive](https://archive.org/download/utzoo-wiseman-usenet-archive/news061f1.tgz) contains a different implementation by Lenny Tropiano.

Comment: Interesting, so the Stan Lee quote comes from RedHat sysadmins.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too petty, I can't bite my tongue: the phrase "with great power comes great responsibility" was considered trite at least as early as the mid-19th century. Its appropriation by a cartoon strip is relatively recent. (EDIT: Wikipedia seems to cite it in French at least as early as 1793). This I write despite it being completely irrelevant to the answer given here, which is completely accurate in its quoting someone else.

Comment: @Tommy someone is wrong on the Internet!!!  :)

Comment: @Tommy And Leif Ericsson got to America before Columbus, but we don't have a holiday for him, because his voyages didn't lead to  permanent settlements.  The committer knew of that phrase from Uncle Ben, so Marvel gets the credit.

Comment: @MontyHarder Leif Erikson Day was two days ago, naturally I refused to come to work and will instead insist on working on Columbus Day.